# Azure function app running indefinitely on webhook trigger

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

The Below function app code should execute while a webhook is triggered. The below code runs fine. But eventhough the webhook is triggered once. The below code runs indefinitely. Is anything is wrong in the below code which cause the issue.

**Index.js**

```
module.exports = async (context, req) => {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
  const contentful = require("contentful-management");
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    accessToken: "test",
  });

  const spaceId = "test";
  const environmentId = "test";
  try {
    const space = await client.getSpace(spaceId);
    const environment = await space.getEnvironment(environmentId);
    let response = await environment.getEntry(context.req.body.sys.id);
    const firstEntry = response;
    context.log(firstEntry);
    if (
      firstEntry.fields.previousSlug != undefined &&
      firstEntry.fields.slug != firstEntry.fields.previousSlug
    ) {
      const testingContentTypeId = "redirectManager"; // Replace with the actual content type ID
      const testingEntry = await environment.createEntry(testingContentTypeId, {
        fields: {
          id: { "en-GB": firstEntry.fields.internalDocumentId["en-GB"] },
          redirectSlug: {
            "en-GB": firstEntry.fields.previousSlug["en-GB"],
          },
          currentSlug: { "en-GB": firstEntry.fields.slug["en-GB"] },
        },
      });
      testingEntry.publish();
    }
    firstEntry.fields.previousSlug = firstEntry.fields.slug;
    var result = await firstEntry.update();
    await result.publish();
  } catch (error) {
    context.res = {
      body: error,
    };

    return "test";
  };
};
```

**Function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: one option is to  change the code to a timmer trigger So the code runs for every time you have set

Answer (score 0):

*In order to close or stop your Function, Make sure you add **`context.done();`** in your Function code like below to stop the Function task from running.*

**My *Http Trigger* code that calls one API acting as a webhook with `context.done();`:-**

```js
var axios = require('axios');
 
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
 
    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            handleGetRequest(context);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                handlePostRequest(context, chunk.toString());
            });
            break;
        default:
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Invalid HTTP method. Only GET and POST are supported." })
            };
            context.done();
    }

    context.log('Function execution completed.');
};
 
function handleGetRequest(context) {
    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(function (response) {
            context.res = {
                status: response.status,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(response.data)
            };
            context.log('GET request handling completed.');
            context.done();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            context.res = {
                status: error.response ? error.response.status : 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({ error: error.message })
            };
            context.log('Error in GET request handling.');
            context.done();
        });
}
 
function handlePostRequest(context, requestBody) {
    axios.post('https://example.com/api', requestBody)
        .then(function (response) {
            context.res = {
                status: response.status,
                body: JSON.stringify(response.data)
            };
            context.log('POST request handling completed.');
            context.done();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            context.res = {
                status: error.response ? error.response.status : 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({ error: error.message })
            };
            context.log('Stopping function execution.');
            context.done();
        });
}
```

**Output :-**

[image]

Output at Browser :

[image] [image]